# How to merge lines with close coordinates into one line in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, merge

The database contains a collection of lines, which have pretty close coordinates (see red lines in the picture). Is it possible to merge these lines and create only one line, that is median of the 3 of them?

[image]

The example of data:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-0.989646 51.808275, -0.989301 51.807894), (-0.989579 51.808201, -0.989227 51.807814), (-0.989104 51.807676, -0.989476 51.808085))')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you want with the line. For example, do you want it to have the same length as the longest line, or the shortest line?

One approximation: take the convex hull of your lines (a polygon), and then use `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis()` to get the approximate centerline.

Using your MultiLineString:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal; -- if it's not installed
SELECT ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(
         ST_ConvexHull(
           ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-0.989646 51.808275, -0.989301 51.807894), (-0.989579 51.808201, -0.989227 51.807814), (-0.989104 51.807676, -0.989476 51.808085))')));
```

Comment: I need to get the green line as in the picture. So your code snippet does exactly what I need.